# Perform an aggregate function on an aggregate or a subquery for dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a query where I select a count of ticket status for tickets issued this month and a count of ticket status for those entered last month, and so on. Because it's almost like 3 different where clauses(Cause its three different status and I need them side by side). I tried this code.

```
 SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN  DATEPART(MONTH,recordInputDate)=DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)) 
 THEN COUNT(ticketNumber) 
 ELSE 0
 END
 ) AS ticketNumber
 FROM TICK_ticketRecord
```

It was my intention that this would work however i get the error regarding sub query and im not sure how to handle it as I cant assign the dates i want to work with to a variable.

Or if i could combine the following into one query

```
 SELECT COUNT(ticketNumber) 
 FROM TICK_ticketRecord
 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,recordInputDate)=DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)) 
AND tickStatus=2

 SELECT COUNT(ticketNumber) 
 FROM TICK_ticketRecord
 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,recordInputDate)=DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)) 
AND tickStatus=3
```

Regards

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Please read GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply any filtering you want in the `WHERE` clause, in order to get the whole set of the records you want to count. Then use *conditional aggregation* to selectively count records having different `tickStatus` values:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ticketNumber = 2 THEN 1 END) AS status_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ticketNumber = 3 THEN 1 END) AS status_3
FROM TICK_ticketRecord
WHERE 
   DATEPART(MONTH,recordInputDate) = DATEPART(MONTH, 
                                              DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0, GETDATE())-1,0)) 
   AND 
   tickStatus IN (2,3)
```